# ASP.NET non-admin user can access admin-only page using URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm building a site where users can login in and view data while the admin can login and view data plus creating/editing/deleting users.

I have created this and it all works, users get taken to the data page and the admin is has the option to view the data page or user page. but there's one big flaw, when a user logins in, in the URL if they type in the correct address to the EditUser page, they can view it which gives them the control to edit users as well.

Is there a way I can deny users from seeing this page and just allow the admin?

I do have a separate database for the admin and users.

Comment: What type of authentication are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a session for each admin that log in, if you leave the page accessible with just a link, everyone can login. I'm not an expert in html but i think you should use something like REST link (https://blog.restcase.com/restful-api-authentication-basics/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you have proper server-side authentication and authorization (all your back-end requests should go through authentication and authorization of every user request). It sounds like you might already be doing authentication of users, but you are not doing authorization.

Simply put, authentication is finding the answer to "Who made this request?". Authorization is finding the answer to "Is this user allowed to make this request?".

All your back-end requests should verify the user who is making the request (by matching a username+password or a token to what's in the database), then you'll know if that user is a normal member or an admin. Then ensure that your requests which are only for admins only work if the authenticated user has admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend creating your own validation\role provider system. It is pretty complicated to do that correctly and prevent all of the possible attacks plus properly encrypt and store login information. Use one of the already available solutions like "Identity" [link](https://www.asp.net/identity)

Answer (score 0):

In my ASP.Net Razor site, the first thing I check on the page loading is to see if the current user belongs to the admin group and if not I redirect them to the home page.

Comment: Not a bad idea! Didn't think of that. Thanks Phil.